# How should this server block look for a successful nginx ssl installation?

Tags: ssl, nginx

So I am reviewing this server block configuration and honestly it does not look as boilerplate as I had hoped and I need to successfully install an ssl.

The file is /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl on;
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/biossantibodies.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

And then there is another file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

So I am not even sure which one of these I should be working in.

Comment: 'Install an SSL' is meaningless. You need to instal an SSL *certificate*.

Comment: that is correct @EJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below has a good example of what you need to configure ssl for NGINX.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate